# Resize a single UICollectionViewCell, Is it possible?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm wondering if it is possible to resize a single UICollectionViewCell?
I've been looking at things like layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath & layoutAttributesForElementsInRect but they both require you to manually set the frame of each item which becomes more trouble because i have to calculate the frames again once i resize a cell.. My plan is to be able to select a single cell and have it expand to fit the width of the screen and push all the other cells down while the other cells maintain their columns and rows.

has anybody achieved this?

thanks

Comment: Is this your layout or is it the built-in flow layout?

Comment: I started sub classing, UICollectionFlowLayout

Comment: Well, you don't need to. The flow layout has a delegate. You can make the items any size you want to. Just implement `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    collectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)

    if selectedIndexPath == indexPath {
        size.width = CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.frame)
    }
    return size
}
```

Yes, it's that simple.

(Though that does not answer the question if that's a good idea. You will see when you implement it ;)

Comment: This is great, but is there a way to have the cells no longer selected animate their resize too?  They just collapse immediately and it is jarring compared to the expanding one.